# How to ls in etcd v3?

Tags: key-value, etcd

How can I ls "/config" directory to get "/a /b /c" in etcd v3?

I don't want to "get /config --prefix" and compare all keys for 10000 times.

```
/config
.../a/
.../b/
....../xxx # about 100000 keys
.../c/
```

Answer (score 2):

*ls* seems to have been deliberately omitted in v3, but in your case something like this can work:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get /config --prefix
```